# Localizing component labels at run-time

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, localization, tabnavigator

I have a few different tabs in a navigator defined like this : (removed client specific domain)

```
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    xmlns:container="com.*****.shop.admin.container.*"
                    width="100%" height="100%"
                    implements="com.*****.common.container.IScreen"
                    xmlns:services="com.****.shop.admin.services.*"
                    label="Service Types">
```

I have resource bundles for different locales, en_US looks like this :

```
ServicesScreen.label=Service Types
```

When I try to do this, it doesn't work :

```
...    
... 
label="{resourceManager.getString('resources','ServicesScreen.label')}"
```

Instead of getting my resource bundle entry, I get something weird looking in my GUI like :

```
Shop0.ShopSkin9._ShopSkin_Group1.contentScroller.ScrollerSkin13.contentGroup.vsMain.AdminView154.SkinnableContainerSkin159.contentGroup.subNavItems.opCodeScreen
```

My resource bundles work in other cases, for instance labels next to form input fields, etc...  The code compiles, however, and no errors are actually thrown (compile or run-time).  I tried assigning the value to a variable and using that variable in the label field, however that caused a compile error.

I tried calling a setter method on creation complete of the component, but that didn't resolve the issue either.

**How do I localize my tab labels, and can I do so dynamically at run-time?**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, so the only think I can come up with is that maybe `resources` is some kind of reserved word you can't use for resource bundle names. I had mystery-bug of my own once by naming my bundle `components`, which conflicted with a bundle of the same name that exists in the SDK.

Comment: I will try to change it, however my bundle works for all of the other entries, like images, text input labels, etc, while using the bundle named `resources.properties`. It's really only when it comes to properties defined in the views' "constructors" so to speak

Comment: Go back to using your approach with the setter method. Then step through the code with the debugger. If you step into the `resourceManager.getString()` method you should see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll self-answer this one, although credit goes to Sunil D.  I don't know why it didn't work earlier while I was testing, I must've missed something the first time, but here goes.  first I added:

```
creationComplete="init(event)">
```

And then in that method body I did :

```
    protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        this.label = resourceManager.getString('resources','opCodeScreen.title');
    }
```

And it works like a charm.  honestly I'm pretty sure I did this exact same test this morning, but I guess not.  Sunil If you want to make your comment an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

EDIT: change the text at run-time, add `currentStateChange` that calls aforementionned method

Cheers!